# Is there a way to turn this strut/Spring into a Nurbs Curve?

Tags: add-on, edit-mode, bezier-curves

I have a spring that I want to convert into curve (Nurbs Curve specifically)
Is there a way to turn the mesh into a curve without having to trace it out.
This  mesh is way to decimated so clitic links doesn't work. the top picture is the object and the bottom picture is how I want it to convert to...Is this possible?

[image]

[image]

Comment: hello could you please share your file? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: I just shared it :) thank you for the help in advance

Comment: please copy the link it gives you and paste here

Comment: https://pasteall.org/blend/d15c54ec43f648a59c4c7b570f8baf91

Comment: Im very sorry I am new at this

Comment: I thought I could select an edge loop all along but the topology is triangulated so I'm not sure there's any simple solution (you can merge by distance but it will be a bit trash)

Comment: its ok Moonboots, thank you for the help :)

Comment: I'm afraid the simplest way would be to recreate with for example the Add Curves addon and Curve > Spirales > Archemedian, but maybe someone will find a solution